# How can I summarize the probability results, that I got with a loop? (Java)

Tags: java, loops, sum, probability

I'm wondering if is there a way to summarize the results of probability that I got through a loop? So I can know how many successful hits there were, given x number of attempts. Right now I just get a stream of 1 or 0 statements (1 for a successful hit, 0 for fail), not very practical. It looks like this:

```
public class doGry {
public static void main(String[] args ) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        // chance to hit (h) = 35% + (ma - md)
        // 8% < h < 90%
        double ma = 20;
        double md = 10;
        double probability;

        System.out.println("probability of success " + (probability = 35 + (ma - md)));

        double probab2 = probability / 100;
        double r = Math.random();

        int roll;
        if (r <= probab2) roll = 1;
        else roll = 0;
        System.out.println(roll);


    }

}
```

}

Comment: You can use a variable for that, set it to `0` outside of the loop. Each time it's successful, increment its value by 1.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works in all cases besides the first hit. It never counts the first hit, it shows 0, but from the second one on it goes fine. So that everything works, I have to set the variable to 1. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few variables that can be initialized outside of for-loop since you are not modifying its value, so no need it initialize it again and again. 
Using a variable `count`, for keeping track of successful hits. For each successful hit, increment its value by 1.

```
public class doGry {
    public static void main(String[] args ) {
        double ma = 20;
        double md = 10;
        double probability = 35 + (ma - md);
        double probab2 = probability / 100;
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {

            System.out.println("probability of success " + probability);
            
            double r = Math.random();

            if (r <= probab2) 
            {
                System.out.println("1");
                count++;
            }
            else 
                System.out.println("0");
        }
        System.out.println("Succesful hits " + count);
    }
}
```

Comment: @shrimpy  earlier you said it didn't count the first hit, what was the difference compared to my  code?

Comment: I did it wrong, I guess. I took your advice, and instead of adding a condition under the 'if' in my original code, I added another conditional statement outside the loop (something like 'if roll == 1, then count++). Sorry I'm a total noob.

Comment: @shrimpy  it's fine, everyone starts from there. Since this satisfies your questions, accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add in a variable to keep track of how many successful rolls occurred, and then divide that by the total number of rolls using a double like so

```
public class doGry
{
    public static void main(String[] args )
    {
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            // chance to hit (h) = 35% + (ma - md)
            // 8% < h < 90%
            double ma = 20.0;
            double md = 10.0;
            double probability;
    
            System.out.println("probability of success " + (probability = 35 + (ma - md)));
    
            double probab2 = probability / 100;
            double r = Math.random();
    
            int roll;
            if (r <= probab2) {roll = 1; total++;}
            else roll = 0;
            System.out.println(roll);
        }
        System.out.println("total: " + total/50.0);
    }
}
```

Notice in the final System.out.println statement, the total is being divided by 50.0 (and not 50) as the .0 indicates you want a double division and not integer division, the latter of which throws away any remainder decimal values.